# I am getting error while parsing JSON data in ejs template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, ejs

Syntax Error: Unexpected token ')' in pages\data ejs while compiling ejs.

I am fetching jsonData which has two fields question and answer from a JSON file and applying a if condition to remove any question with key as favicon.ico

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JSON Data Rendering</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>JSON Data</h1>
    <ul>
        <%= jsonData.forEach(item=> { %>
            <li><strong>QUESTION</strong>
                <%= if(item.question !='favicon.ico' ){ %>
                    <%= item.question %>, <strong>ANSWER</strong>
                        <%= item.answer %>
                            <%= } %>
            </li>
            <%= }); %>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>```


I WANT THAT THIS CODE HAS NO ERROR
````